# Как можно менять состояние служб через cmd?

Tags: windows, bat, windows-service

Недавно задался вопросом можно ли в `.bat` менять состояние служб или тип запуска, так как после каждой переустановки Windows , приходилось долго настраивать службы и только сейчас додумался сделать данный `.bat` файл. Возможно кому-нибудь пригодиться.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай уточню ,где нужно брать названия служб:

```
WIN + R -> services.msc -> (нужная вам служба) -> Свойства -> Имя службы:(здесь будет указано имя)
```

Менять тип запуска служб можно следующим ключом в команде:

```
sc config (название службы) - команда
start= Disabled | Auto | Demand - ключ

Disabled - Отключена
Auto - Автоматически
Demand - Запуск вручную
    
sc config DcpSvc start=Disabled - пример полноценной команды (DcpSvc - это название службы)
```

Менять состояние служб можно следующим образом:

```
sc start | pause | continue | stop

start - Запустить
pause - Приостановка
continue - Возобновление приостановленной службы
stop - Остановить

sc stop DcpSvc - пример полноценной команды (DcpSvc как и в первом случае название службы)
```